# Does Shell-in-a-Box offer double encryption?

Tags: encryption, tls, linux, openssl, ssh

[Shell-In-A-Box](https://github.com/shellinabox/shellinabox) offers SSH access to a server via HTTPS using a standard web browser. Both SSH and HTTPS encrypt traffic payloads. Does that mean Shell-In-A-Box offers double encryption since it performs SSH inside HTTPS or I simply misunderstand the whole concept?

Comment: *"Shell-In-A-Box __offers SSH access__ to a server via HTTPS... "* - __it doesn't__, which makes the basic assumption of your question wrong and thus the question obsolete. Shell-In-A-Box offers a remote login shell inside a terminal emulation which can be accessed through the web browser. While SSH is the most common way for remote shells today it is not the only way, i.e. telnet or Shell-In-A-Box or other technologies are possible too. Thus, don't just assume that any remote shell implies SSH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

No.

The client connection to the webserver may be secured using TLS, commonly known as https. The connection from the web server hosting shell-in-a-box to the server you are controlling *may* be via ssh.

Comment: I have two machines involved i this scenario. A client machine and a Linux server with Shell-In-A-Box (SIAB) running. Are you saying HTTPS sessions from client are terminated by server before initiating SSH to loopback address?